# Linking Data To Multiple Entities in Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I am designing a database (simplified here) to hold parts. Each part has its own unique PartID. We can store the parts in different containers:

- Reusable Bags
- Boxes
- Pallets

It's important that we have specific different information for each container:

- **Bags:** ID, MaterialType, Volume, HandleType
- **Boxes:** ID, Height, Width, Length
- **Pallets:** ID, DateCreated, NumberOfTimesUsed, Color

**My question:** What is the best way to link parts to these multiple container entities?

In my mind the simplest way conceptually is to create ContainerType and ContainerID columns in the Part table. I'm hesitant to do that, because you essentially break referential integrity having a column with an unenforced foreign key to multiple tables, because it's illegal.

We could make a big container table with all possible properties of a container, but that seems very cumbersome too.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Personally I'd create a `container` table with the columns `ID, ContainerType, MaterialType, Volume, HandleType, Height, Width, Length, DateCreated, NumberOfTimesUsed,` and `Color`. You'd have a ton of NULL values but it would make joining so much easier and you could avoid repeating a lot of data in the parts table. You'd just join to an ID number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that has no great answer in MySQL.
There are several approaches, each has pros and cons.

**Option #1 - Table full of NULLs**

As suggested in the comments, a `containers` table that will have all columns, many of them NULL because they will not be relevant for the 2 of the 3 container types. 
It's very easy to use such a table in `SELECT` and `JOIN`, but in this case the DB can't help you validate you data. You can easily insert bags that have a length or boxes that don't have one, and the DB can't enforce it.

**Option #2 - Move the problem to the connecting table**

In this approach, you are moving the problem from the tables that store the containers, to the tables that store the parts location.

There are 3 separate containers tables:

- bags
- boxes
- pallets

And one table for connecting parts to containers:

- parts_to_containers

with the columns:

- part_id
- container_type
- container_id

This option is better if you handle the inventory of containers independently and often. It makes your work with containers very easy, and places the problematic part on working with the placement of parts in containers.

You can still write a query with 3 `LEFT JOIN`s that will get you info about the container for each part.

**One more thing**

If you expect to have many more types of containers, none of the above will be easy to scale. If more and more container types are added, you may want a completely different approach where all *common* container fields are in one main `containers` table, and all the other *container attributes* are in a `container_attributes` table with `container_id`, `attribute_name` and `attribute_value`. One of the attributes will be the container type, others will  be color, width, volume, etc.

This is a very flexible model for objects with a variety of different attrobutes that change over time.

Comment: You're not supposed to thank people in comments, but I'm going to do it anyway because this answer was great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb in a one to many relationship between tables is: the primary key of the single side of the relationship acts as a foreign key in the many side of the relationship in order to preserve referential integrity.

Create a table called `containers` with primary key column `container`.`id` and other columns such as `container`.`name`, `container`.`createdOn`, `container`.`lastOpenedOn`.  The primary key `container`.`id` from table `container` is added to your parts table as a foreign key column called `parts`.`container_id`.

Comment: Yikes! maybe I should have specified better, but it's a 1 to many relationship. Many parts can live in one container and I only have one parts table.